# Generate subnet mask (uint32_t or s_addr) from the mask length (for ipv4 and ipv6 addresses)

Tags: c, ip-address, mask, subnet

I have my input list of ipv4 and ipv6 addresses which are subnetted. I want to find their subnet mask in `s_addr` or `uint_32_t` form so that I can check if a given IP address belongs to the input list of IP addresses. 
So how do we generate subnet mask (like 255.255.255.0) when we encounter an IP address (say 156.67.154.0/24)?

I tried:

```
uint32_t subnet_mask=0xFFFFFFFFU & -(1U << (32 - prefix))
```

but the above approach gives: `0.255.255.255`

Answer (score 0):

Try `(1U << (32 - prefix)) - 1`.